# How can I create a AutoValue class with generics?

Tags: java, android, auto-value

I would like to have a data class using AutoValue and one of the property is generic,
wondering what I am doing wrong ?

```
public abstract class Data<T> {

    public static <T> Data createData(T value, Integer index) {
        return new AutoValue_Data<T>(value, index);
    }

    @NotNull
    public abstract T value();

    @NotNull
    public abstract Integer index();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like it should work, with one line that should get a warning fixed:

```
public static <T> Data createData(T value, Integer index) {
```

should be

```
public static <T> Data<T> createData(T value, Integer index) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot generic T after Data, your code should be:

```
public abstract class Data<T> {

    public static <T> Data <T> createData(T value, Integer index) {
        return new AutoValue_Data<T>(value, index);
    }

    @NotNull
    public abstract T value();

    @NotNull
    public abstract Integer index();
}
```